# Is a grilled cheese sandwich still considered a grilled cheese sandwich if it contains a third slice of bread?

Tags: cheese, sandwich, grilled

From what I understand, once something is added to a grilled cheese sandwich other than sauce or seasoning, it ceases to be a grilled cheese sandwich and instead becomes a melt. But what if you put another slice of bread in between two layers of cheese?

Essentially, bread, cheese, bread, cheese, bread. Does adding the middle layer of bread cause it to become a "bread melt?"

Comment: This seems like an entirely opinion based question with no definitive answer (like, "is a hot dog a sandwich?", or "is Chicago deep dish a pizza or casserole?").

Comment: For the rest of the world… the 90% of us who have never heard of a 'melt' as a specific food item, could you clarify? [Let's assume for this exercise that we all know what happens when you heat most cheeses & we also know what toast is]

Comment: @Tetsujin - "a sandwich with melted cheese" - from the widely available website, m-w.com (Merriam-Webster)

Comment: …which tells me everything I already know without the merest hint of any new information. I may as well ask if a cheese toasty is the same as a toasted cheese or a cheese on toast.

Answer (score 2):

There's no exact answer to this, I would classify this as a triple decker grilled cheese sandwich rather than a melt as you are adding more bread rather than a filling. I would toast the middle piece of bread first to make sure you get a decent crunchy texture.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughtful cooking suggestion, @GgD. I will toast the bread of middle.

Answer (score 1):

A burger with a third slice of bread is still a burger. Why would it be different for grilled cheese?

Comment: You can add anything to a burger, and it's still a burger. Once you add something to a grilled cheese sandwich, it's a melt.

Comment: https://www.foodnetwork.com/restaurants/photos/craziest-grilled-cheese-in-the-country If restaurants can sell these as grilled cheese, I think its fine.

Comment: Not grilled cheeses. Source:  https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-difference-between-a-grilled-cheese-and-a-melt